# Python: Get Folder containing specific files extension

Tags: python

I'm trying to find how to get a folder list that contains a specific file extension and that will gave me only the folder and containing only unique folder. And the fastest way.

Is there a one liner for that?

so if I have
c:\folderA\test1.tga
c:\folderA\test2.tga
c:\folderA\test3.tga
c:\folderB\test4.tga

I want
c:\folderA\
c:\folderB\

cheers

Comment: Yet another "help me to solve my homework"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a one liner but it would look better if you used more lines.

```
set(folder for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk('/') for file_ in files if os.path.splitext(file_)[1] == '.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a one-liner, but:

```
def findFolder(root, suffix):
  for dirName in os.listdir(root):
    dirPath = os.path.join(root, dirName)
    if os.path.isdir(dirPath):
      for fileName in os.listdir(dirPath):
        if fileName.endswith(suffix):
          yield dirPath  # or dirName, whatever you like better
          break
```